# Sybase timestamp converting

Tags: t-sql, sybase

Sybase timestamp converting :

Please suggest me some nice document for Sybase Date and timestamp converting.

Example :

Converting date format
Coveting short date to long date

Using below query, I need some information for conversion number  :

```
select  CONVERT( VARCHAR( 20 ), av.logDatetime   , 112 ) + ":"+ CONVERT( VARCHAR( 20 ), av.logDatetime   , 108 )
            from dbo.ProcessLog av
```

Please suggest me some doc,Thanks!

Comment: Try [this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/defining_menus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp you will find the documentation for every sybase product.